# Solving a parallel RC circuit without knowing the capacitor resistance

Tags: circuit-analysis, passive-networks

I Have the following circuit scheme (I have to find the U):
$$R_1=10, R_2=20 (\Omega); A_1->i=0.6,  A_2->i=0.8(A)$$

[image]

I have a problem with calculating the impedance **Z** since I need it to calculate he **U**, but I don't know how to calculate it since **Xc** (capacitor resistance)**** is not given.

What I've done so far:
$$i_1=i_2+i_3=1.4 A;\quad U_{r1}=i_1*R_1=14V;\quad U_{r2}=i_1*R_2=12V; $$
and after that I get stuck because I haven't got the **Xl** (inductor resistance) to solve for **Ur3**? How should I proceed?

*I hope this question is appropriate for this community (my first question).*

**EDIT:**
Results that are given:
[image]

Comment: Presumably the point in your course teaches you that you can assume the amp-meters to represent zero resistance? Hopefully that's a decent hint.

Comment: But I wouldn't even take them into account in my problem, I just use the facet they give me the value of the current through that branch. I think I didn't quite understand...

Comment: check my answers

Comment: check my improved answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remember current of capacitor and resistor not same, like this picture :
[image]

Comment: wow, that's amazing, well deserved 50 points! I m, sorry but I haven to wait 14 hours to award you with it.

Comment: Could you just explain why did you use the cos theorem, I've never seen that before begin used in such examples?

Comment: The calculations are almost correct. However the currents I1 and I2 are swapped This brings the voltage over R2 at 12V (20*0,6) Entering this correction brings Vu to 19.7 V

Comment: O I see. tnx for the correction. Without you guy I would have never solved this.

Comment: oh yes sry my bad i wrong the current of R1 fix it it's work

Comment: Uh what a complicated way. The point is we already have I1 as resistive and capacitive componets I1=I2+I3, then you find modulus, angle and then back to components. There's no need for this round back trip. Circuit can be solved in one single line. \$U_1=U_\text{R2}+R_1(I_2+I_3)=R_2 I_2+ +R_1(I_2+I_3)= 20\,\Omega \times 0.6\,\text{A}+10\,\Omega\times (0.6+\text{j} 0.8\,\text{A})=18+\text{j}8\,\text{V}\$  which in modulus yields \$|U_1|=\sqrt{(18\,\text{V})^2+(8\,\text{V})^2}\approx 19.7\,\text{V}\$

Comment: Thank you for this comment.  Did not use complex calculations for more than 50 years. Never the less you are right